# How to customize alert message produced from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, alert

I'm using AJAX to submit a form. It produces an alert message at the end.
Alert messages say they are from localhost. Can I customize them?

[image: AJAX code]
[image: alert message]

Answer (score 0):

Original alert boxes can't be altered(security reasons).
You can add custom JS alertbox.
Check here with JQuery:[//labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)